# Change Column Values in a Dataframe column using Pandas

Tags: pandas, replace, jupyter-notebook, slice

The data type of the column is object. but, i still map it to string using `astype(str)`. even used `temp['Injury Severity'].str.strip()` to remove spaces from column values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEO7R.png)

I want to replace all "Fatal(0)",Fatal(1)"... with only "Fatal". so i used.`temp['Injury Severity'] = temp['Injury Severity'].replace('Fatal(0)','Fatal',inplace = True)`.

But did not work. i also tried `temp.loc[temp['Injury Severity'] == 'Fatal(0)','Injury Severity'] = temp['Injury Severity'].replace('Fatal(0)','Fatal',inplace = True)`

In addition is tried `str.replace` but did not work out.lastly also used `regex = True` but no changes was observed.It still remains the same.

Comment: `temp['Injury Severity'] = temp['Injury Severity'].str.replace('Fatal(0)','Fatal')`

Answer (score 1):

[image: 1]

I think it is solved. It seems that the values were having leading and trailing spaces in the name of values.Thanks alot for the help everyone !!

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

temp['Injury Severity'].replace('Fatal(0)','Fatal',inplace = True)

No need to assign it again.